# Change css :onhover distance

Tags: css, webkit, onhover

I was wondering if there was a way to make css `:onhover` occur sooner (i.e. I'm 10px away from a link, and `:onhover` calls, while still 10px away).

**Edit:** I'm trying to figure out a way to change the `:onhover` distance for a scrollbar.

**Edit 2:** Here's the code:

```css
html {
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 30px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.1);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.8); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **`CSS border property`** to the element which then will receive the hover event.

**Reference 1:** [**jsFiddle Proximity Detector**](http://jsfiddle.net/NCvJL/1)

Edit: I now see you've re-written a *major edit* to your Question.

I've looked at your code and have come up with a method that you might like for Chrome's scrollbar!

**Reference 2:** [**jsFiddle Scrollbar Proximity Detector**](http://jsfiddle.net/X3ApY/)

Comment: Whoa. Looks like you nailed it with your second example.

Comment: Wow! That second example works just the way I wanted it to. Thanks!

Comment: And all with css too, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I find the CSS methods for solving this intrusive. Transparent `<divs>`, extra markup, and `margin/padding` methods can get in the way of surrounding UI. But those would be the pure CSS methods to try if they work for you.

If you're open to using Javascript to solve this, you can capture `mousemove` on the `body` and calculate the relation.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/Buaze/

#### Script

```js
function isNear( element, distance, event ) {
    var left = element.documentOffsetLeft - distance,
        top = element.documentOffsetTop - distance,
        right = left + element.clientWidth + ( 2 * distance ),
        bottom = top + element.clientHeight + ( 2 * distance ),
        x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;
    return ( x > left && x < right && y > top && y < bottom );
};

document.body.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function () {
    var near = document.getElementById( 'near' );

    if( isNear( near, 20, event ) ) {
        near.textContent = 'is near!';
    } else {
        near.textContent = '';
    };
} );           

window.Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'documentOffsetTop', {
    get: function () { 
        return this.offsetTop + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetTop : 0 );
    }
} );

window.Object.defineProperty( Element.prototype, 'documentOffsetLeft', {
    get: function () { 
        return this.offsetLeft + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetLeft : 0 );
    }
} );
```

#### HTML

```html
<div id="near"></div>
```

#### CSS

```css
#near {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @CharlesL I missed that edit. No, Javascript cannot access a scrollbar like that.

Comment: @CharlesL, JavaScript can tell if vertical overflow has been set, thus indicating a scrollbar is visible. That said, it's a matter of using the current scrollbar "CSS style" along with browser's viewport "right side" that determines scrollbar location. When all is said and done, your script can work for that too! (Extra work for scroll-top and fixed vertical size of scroll handle is needed) **+1 for a great answer nevertheless!**

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but you could position a transparent div that's 10 pixels larger than your target element directly over it, then give that an `onhover` function with Javascript. I don't think this is possible with pure CSS, though.

Comment: just gotta make sure it doesnt interfere with any functionality in the near region of the link really.

Comment: That's true. This kind of problem can really get hairy--positioning the div below the link via the `z-index` property might avoid that particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use javascript, you could set a parent wrapping container with `padding:10px` and set the `:hover` selector on that instead of your child element.

Comment: it depends if it interferes with surrounding elements.  Using javascript you can set a fixed position div ontop of everything as an overlay and move the div on scroll to always match the position of the link.

Comment: @JonTaylor yes this is a good point, but I think positioning the parent absolutely with the child set to relative could be a reliable (though messy) workaround.